# Output dictionary to textbox in C#

Tags: c#, forms, dictionary, textbox, output

I have a dictionary myDataItems which contains string and double. I'm passing values to the dictionary from 2 textboxes, 1 textbox passes the string value, the other the double. I was wondering how I can get the Dictionary items displayed in a 3rd textbox(txtOutput) I'm using for output purposes?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{
   private Dictionary<string, double> myDataItems = new Dictionary<string, double>();
   private string dataName;
   private double dataCost;

   private void dataItemSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      dataName = dataNameInput.Text;
      dataCost = Convert.ToDouble(dataCostInput.Text);
      myDataItems.Add(dataName, dataCost);
      txtOutput.Text = myDataItems.ToString();
   }
}
```

Comment: `foreach (var pair in myDataItems) { /* add pair.Key and pair.Value to  txtOutput */ }`

Comment: foreach(KeyValuePair<string, double> pair in myDataItems){}

Comment: I tried something similar to codesparkle's solution and it doesn't work. I'm just looking for the pairs to be displayed in the textbox, for example:

You have selected "key" at price "value"

Comment: Scott show the code that you have tried.. you need to do this in a foreach loop show us the example that you tried where you say it doesn't work.. paste the code into your question

Comment: Is there a way to just select the double from each pair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach:

```
var lines = myDataItems.Select(kv => kv.Key + ": " + kv.Value.ToString());
txtOutput.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
```

Remember to add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: much nicer solution Linq is like google "It's your friend.. :)

Comment: You won't need the `ToString()`, by the way.

Comment: @codesparkle: i know, but it doesn't hurt and shows that the value originally is not a string and makes it easier to change the formatting of the double, f.e. `kv.Value.ToString("N2")`.

Comment: I'll need to read up on LINQ I think. I'm pretty new to this. Thanks for the help though lads :)

Answer (score 0):

```
txtOutput.Lines = myDataItems.Select(x => x.Key + " : " + x.Value).ToArray();
```